# Include a HTML file in a LaTeX-beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pdftex, html

I have a HTML file available at this URL :

http://khamphouj.iiens.net/ENSIIE/ENSTA/Plot%201.html

And I'd like to put it into my beamer presentation. I don't want it to be static like a .png or .jpg picture, I want, during my presentation (and in my pdf, as you've understood) to be able to hover datas and see all the features of the html document : I want this functionnality to work when I have my mouse on the graph:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% What Packages should I add ?
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Julia performances}
    % What code should I use ?
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put a link in your presentation that link to the website and open it in your preferred browser

Comment: PDF is not HTML. You may model this with PDF layers and buttons.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you for your comment samcarter, I will consider this option if there is no other better possibility. Indeed, I'd have to exit full screen of my beamer, leave my pdf etc. that wouldn't be as good as having the html file within my pdf

Comment: @J.Khamphousone You don't have to exit your full screen beamer just because you open a link (at least not with the pdf viewers I know)

Comment: @samcarter which pdf viewer do you use ? Mine won't let me access an URL without exiting full screen. I use Preview in OSX.

Comment: @AlexG & samcarter, ok, according to your comments, what I want doesn't sound possible ^^ I'll check buttons in PDF, and if it doesn't work, I'll use samcarter's solution :)

Comment: @J.Khamphousone For example with adobe reader I can open the url from within presentation mode

Comment: @samcater Hum, ok, I've badly express myself, Adobe Reader will redirect you to an other application when you click on the link, (that was quite previsible), instead of showing the html file within Adobe (or within the PDF). But I understand, that doesn't sound possible

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

Include a static image as preview which is linked to the website

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \href{http://khamphouj.iiens.net/ENSIIE/ENSTA/Plot 1.html}{\includegraphics[height=.99\textheight]{newplot}}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a possibility even if it wasn't what I firstly wanted, I'll use it if noone finds better :)